# How to send runicast message to itself?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I'm studying a wireless sensor network and I'm implementing a distributed algorithm. What I want that it sends a runicast message to itself.

I tried to send runicast message to '&rimeaddr_node_addr', but it timedout.

runicast_send(&runicast, **&rimeaddr_node_addr**, MAX_RETRANSMISSIONS);

```
runicast_open(&runicast, 144, &runicast_callbacks);    
message *msg = malloc(sizeof(msg));
msg->type = DISCOVER;
msg->size = sizeof(*msg);
packetbuf_copyfrom(&msg, sizeof(msg));
runicast_send(&runicast, &rimeaddr_node_addr, MAX_RETRANSMISSIONS);
```

So, I couldn't send runicast to itself. Could you help me please?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't think this functionality is supported by the Rime stack. What added value there would be?

Comment: Because I want to implement a algorithm. And to trigger the algortihm, one of nodes should sends a message to itself.
If you wonder the algorithm: https://dogukanarkan.com/thesis/1985--Awerbuch--A%20New%20Distributed%20Depth%20First%20Search%20Algorithm.pdf